evil-delete doesn't work as expected. Deletion of whitespaces doesn't work
I am using doom emacs on Mac OS. I am trying to create a clean up whitespace function:
(evil-define-operator my/clean-whitespace (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Change a word."
  :motion evil-forward-word-end
;; Markers R x c y are important so the operator respects the count
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")

(save-excursion


(sp-backward-whitespace)

(set-mark (point))

(sp-forward-whitespace)

(evil-backward-char)

(evil-delete (mark) (point) )
    (deactivate-mark)
 )
)

If there is only one line difference between the whitespaces the function seems to work. However, if there are multiple lines of whitespaces the function stops working. The lines get visually selected however.
Why doesn't the deletion work? If I execute the commands sp-whitespace and evil delete manually it works as it should.

You may not have noticed, but when you reproduce the problem the Echo area has a message flashing for a moment. If you open a *Message* buffer then, you'll see the error. Ideally combining that with a M-x toggle-debug-on-error should invoke a debugger, although for some reason it doesn't work in this case…
Either way, the error is because your caret is at the beginning of line and evil-backward-char can't go back through line boundary. You should use backward-char instead. So the following seems to work correctly:
(evil-define-operator my/clean-whitespace (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Change a word."
  :motion evil-forward-word-end
  ;; Markers R x c y are important so the operator respects the count
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")
  (save-excursion
    (sp-backward-whitespace)
    (set-mark (point))
    (sp-forward-whitespace)
    (backward-char)
    (evil-delete (mark) (point) )
    (deactivate-mark)
    ))


That said, you seem to be overcomplicating. Judging by the name of the function you just want delete-all-space. However, the code of the function contradicts to the name because it leaves out one character, which I presume supposed to be a space (it may also be a TAB but why would you want a tab in the middle of a line?). In that case you might add a (insert " "). I also don't get the point of (save-excursion) in your code, because you delete everything your point was over anyway.
So you probably want this:
(require 'simple)

(evil-define-operator my/whitespace-to-one-space (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Replace whitespace around the point with a single space."
  :motion evil-forward-word-end
  ;; Markers R x c y are important so the operator respects the count
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")
  (delete-all-space)
  (insert " "))


Many thanks, the first function works great. For the second one I don't have delete-all-space function it seems, so I can't use it.

@Rareform try adding a (require 'simple), it should make delete-all-space function available.

Yep, this does the trick. Although in retrospect it worked the first time after reload, then after loading emacs again it doesn't get recognized, weird, but that's fine.

I added the line to the answer. Tbh I'm surprised it's necessary because simple is a very common library. On latest master Emacs that I'm using the function (delete-all-space) is available even if you start Emacs as emacs -Q to ignore any configuration. But well, maybe on older versions it was different or something… Anyway, I added the require line so now it should work on older versions as well.

@Rareform I think I should mention (I didn't in the answer): I am also not sure what that evil-define-operator + "<R><x><c><y>" part is for. I have strong feeling you copied that from elsewhere but have no reason to actually use that code. In particular, the count comment seems unrelated to your code because you don't use count in the function. In my personal Evil config I define quite a few functions that I bind to various Evil motions and I never used evil-define-operator. Maybe you should look into that.

Thanks, I will look into your config. Indeed I copied it from somewhere else and have no idea what it does.
